# Go back to lights-out mode after using the navigation bar?

Tags: java, android, android-view

In one of my activities, I want my UI to be dimmed at all times. When the used presses a navigation button (back, home, recent apps) it should act like normal, but when focus is back to my activity, it should go back to lights-out. Currently, I have lights-out working, but after I press Recent Apps, the lights stay on forever.

How do I make my app always stay in lights-out?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out something that worked.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
                lightsOut();
            }
    }
}
```

Basically, every time my app gets focus, it forces lights out (possibly redundantly, but it doesn't really matter).

Works like a charm!